# Retrieve image stored in in db and save to a file

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, image

I have a customer that is asking to be able to retrieve an image from a Sql Server Db and turn around and save it to a directory on his computer. He wants to be able to do this via a asp.net web page. I am able to retrieve the image from the image as a byte array but have no idea how to take that image and save it to the directory as a file. Anyone have any ideas on how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: What all options did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `Save Method`

```
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream((byte[])YourDataTable.Rows[0]["ImageData"]);
    Picturebox picturebox = new Picturebox();
    picturebox.Image = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
    picturebox.Image.Save("...YourPath", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

Comment: Thanks. What I was looking for. I ended up having to save the image in a temp directory on the server then display a browser save as dialog box for the user to save it locally.

Comment: I'am happy to help you George